# "libsyslog-ng-3.4.8.so: cannot open shared object file" while starting syslog

Tags: shared-library, logging, syslog

I tried to install syslog-ng from source on a new Ubuntu 14.04 install. In anticipation of questioning why I did this, its because there are some changes I want to make to logging systems for experimentation purposes, and I did it in a VM so my personal system is not ruined.

I uninstalled rsyslog and then installed syslog-ng from source. Everything was fine with the install through configure, make and make install. After trying to start syslog from the command line, the following error appeared:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsyslog-ng-3.4.8.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is the output of `ldconfig -p | grep libsyslog-ng
`

Comment: no output to that command

Comment: Does `sudo find /usr -name libsyslog*` find this file?

Comment: that command seems to hav found the item to be located at /usr/local/lib.

Comment: i used the command you suggested but i have got the same error back again.

Comment: Use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"`and try again

Comment: sadly that has not worked either

Comment: Did you try `sudo ldconfig -v`? this will update link and cache used by runtime linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ldconfig manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/ldconfig.8.html):

```
   ldconfig creates the necessary links  and  cache  to  the  most  recent
   shared  libraries  found  in  the  directories specified on the command
   line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/lib
   and  /usr/lib).  The cache is used by the run-time linker, ld.so or ld-
   linux.so.
```

So, when you add a new library on Ubuntu, you should run:

```
   sudo ldconfig -v
```

where `-v` is verbose mode